# Stein's Real Analysis chapter3 Lemma 3.5

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Currently, I'm having difficulty understanding a proof in Stein's Real Analysis. The lemma3.5 is written as follows:

[image]

The proof says it is obvious that E is open because $g$ is continuous. Unfortunately, it is not clear for me that the set E is open. Currently, I'm trying to make a connection between this lemma and the following theorem of undergraduate-level analysis, but this is where I'm stuck on.

**PMA theorem 4.8** A mapping of $f$ of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open for every open set $V$ in $Y$

**PMA theorem 2.24(a)** For any collection of open sets {$G_\alpha$}, $\cup_\alpha G_\alpha$ is open.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E=\bigcup_{h>0} \{x: g(x) \in (0,\infty)\}$ where $g(x)=G(x+h)-G(x)$. Note that $g$ is continuous and union of open sets is open.

Comment: Ah, I got the point now. Thank you very much!